# swipeGesture, touchMoved are called sametime?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uigesturerecognizer

i want to do different operation in SwipeGesture and TouchMoved.But both are called
when we swipe.any help please?

```
 Drecoginizer  = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFromD:)];
Drecoginizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:Drecoginizer];
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you do not want the selector to react on swipe gesture if this swipe is outside of the circle. In this case, in the beginning of the swipe selector you should check if the swipe is over the circle something like so:

```
CGPoint lClick = [recognizer locationOfTouch:0 inView:self.view];

    //Distance from the center of the circle to the taped point
    int lDistance = sqrt(pow(lClick.x - lCircleCenter.x, 2) + pow(lClick.y - lCircleCenter.y, 2));

    if ((int)lDistance > (int)lCircleRadius) {
        return;
    }
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Micro-Op: Get rid of the `sqrt` call and compare against `lCircleRadius*lCircleRadius`.

Comment: hi, have implemented it correcty..but the problem is when i do cross slowly as touch moved, swipe is called.but it is not the down swipe..but downswipe is called

Comment: Well man, the message to the swipe selector is sent on the framework level and for the current time, apple doesn't provide us any solutions to control the sensibility of it. So you should rethink your logic this case.